# Is there a simple way to assign a value only once(first time) inside a loop/repeatedly running method?

Tags: ios, objective-c

For example I want to set different cell height for different screen size. Within a UITableView data source method:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    defaultHeight = self.view.frame.size.height > 480 ? 38 : 32;
    // how to let something like the right side of the = run just once?

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {// no need to remove.
        ...// do something 
        return 20;
    }else {
        ...// do something else 
        return defaultHeight;
    }
}
```

Is there a generic mechanism to assign the defaultHeight only once and without add *additional* "if else"(Just wonder is there some methods I missed)? And inside the repeatedly called method to keep the code structure simple and easy to move around and don't need to bother on what time to init.

Comment: What is wrong with "if else"? If it is clear how the code works that is fine. There is no win for just reducing the number of lines of code, especially at the expense of clarity. If you are trying to make the method faster: don't, at least until you have a performance issue and through profiling you know that is a problem.

Comment: Where is this loop you speak of?

Comment: @rmaddy I should say the repeatedly called method.

Comment: @Zaph Just wonder is there something I missed can reduce the call.

Comment: I agree with @zaph. You're saving nothing significant in terms of time, and possibly making your code harder to read and debug. Leave it alone. Computers are quite fast at math.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, iOS provides a way to do this - use [`dispatch_once`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dispatch_once.3.html) function, and provide a block that performs initialization:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        defaultHeight = self.view.frame.size.height > 480 ? 38 : 32;
    });
    return indexPath.row == 0 ? 20 : defaultHeight;
}
```

iOS guarantees that the block will be executed only upon the initial pass through the function call.

Comment: @Zaph This is up to OP to decide - I mean my guess is as good as anyone else's. Personally, I wouldn't bother with this approach if it were only for performance reasons, but I don't know for sure, because `defaultHeight` potentially could be set from elsewhere.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I know it could be set from elsewhere, just wonder if it is possible to put it inside and don't repeatedly do the same.

Comment: @Al3n This is what `dispatch_once` does - the statement inside the block is executed once, no matter how many times the method is repeated.

Comment: @Al3n Yes, when the block is executed the first time through the program, the invocation of the block will finish before `dispatch_once` returns.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Will the block guaranteed to execute before the next outside statement(return ...)? I'm confusion on GCD "provide systemic, comprehensive improvements to the support for **concurrent** code execution".

Comment: @Al3n `dispatch_once` is safe for concurrent execution: if multiple threads call a method that uses `dispatch_once`, GCD guarantees that only one of these concurrent threads will run the block, and other threads would wait for that block to finish its execution before proceeding.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight So it is different to dispatch_async, the block and other statements executed and finished one by one in the same thread?

Comment: @Al3n Correct, `dispatch_once` is a bit of an "outlier" for the GCD library. It can be used concurrently, but it does not "create new concurrency", unlike many other members of the GCD library.

Comment: Seem a bit overkill when the value can be set in viewDidAppear: method

Comment: @TienDinh That's certainly true. When answering questions like this it's always a tradeoff between suggesting a solution that works best in this specific case vs. answering the question directly. I prefer answering the question, because it becomes relevant to people who may find it through a search engine.

Comment: @TienDinh viewDidAppear is after heightForRowAtIndexPath on startup.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about some conditional operator. Conditional operator is the simplest way which replaces long `if` `else` conditions. Try This!

```
 -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
     return (!indexPath.row)?20:(self.view.frame.size.height > 480)? 38 : 32;
    }
```

Comment: My bad, not mean to remove the existing "if eles". Updated the question.